# Dynamic source & destination language parameters with Node-RED on Bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, node-red, language-translation

Node-RED on Bluemix, using the language translator node, documentation as follows;

> Source and destination language parameters can be configured through
>   the editor panel or set dynamically using the language codes in the
>   following properties, msg.srclang and msg.destlang.

Setting `msg.srclang` & `msg.destlang` doesn't appear to work however. Regardless of the values assigned to these properties, the values defined in the editor are applied when translating.

Is it possible to dynamically set the source/target language values using the language translator node on Bluemix?

Thanks,

Ronan

Answer (score 0):

Message properties passed in only normally apply if the values are left blank in the config editor dialogue

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately the config editor doesn't allow for blank fields :/

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug introduced in a recent revamp of the node. I have raised a bug report and hope to get this fixed soon.